# Setting text for uilabel collection from array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, iboutlet, iboutletcollection

I am having a `UIScrollView` with multiple `UILabels` inside, so I made a collection of `IBOutlets` and connected all the labels. Now the problem is am setting the label text from an array and the value in each label not in order as I have in the array.

```
let timeTables:[TimeTable]  = TimeTable.TimeTableList(array: 
 respnse.responseArray)
        print("From label count \(self.fromLabels.count)")
        print("Time tabele count \(timeTables.count)")
        for (index, item) in timeTables.enumerated() {//
            print(index)
            if index < self.fromLabels.count ,  index < 
  self.toLabels.count{
                self.fromLabels[index].text =  item.from
                print(item.from as Any)
                self.toLabels[index].text =  item.to
                print(item.to as Any)
            }
        }
```

How to make the label display the value in the array order?

Comment: Are you sure that you connected the IBOutlets in the right order?

Comment: Yes am displaying Arabic text, so I have started the connection from right to left in the correct order.

Comment: Can you show your storyboard. I have a feeling that you might need to use a ```UITableView``` instead of the scrollView. Also, let us know how you expect the labels to be and how they actually are being presented.

Comment: @Mac_Play - first, confirm that it's not your **data**... do a `for index in 0..<self.fromLabels.count { self.fromLabels[index].text = \(index) }`. Same with the `toLabels`. If you get what you expected - that is, labels showing Right-to-Left `4 3 2 1 0` - then the problem is with the order of your data. If instead you see `0 1 2 3 4` (or `4 1 0 2 3`), then disconnect the labels from the collection and try re-connecting them again in the desired order.

Comment: @DonMag  (or 4 1 0 2 3) - it displaying like this only. Tried disconnecting and connecting again, still same.  And I checked the order of data, it's fine.

Comment: @DonMag I have printed the label value after setting the text it shows the correct order. What am doing wrong? Is there anything to deal with scrollview, because all my labels are inside scrollview.

Comment: @Mac_Play - is it possible your constraints are not correct, and the labels are being "moved" at run-time?

Comment: @DonMag Clicking on the same variable name  and connecting  '@IBOutlet  var fromLabels  :[UILabel] = [UILabel]()'

Comment: labels are inside stackview so no way to move away. How to share the storyboard pic here?

Comment: @Mac_Play - You can do a screen-cap and edit your post.

Comment: @Mac_Play - try this: In Storyboard, set the text of your labels to `E D C B A`. Then ***do not*** set the text in your code. See if the order (somehow) changes. If it doesn't then in your for-loop, instead of *setting* the text of each label, do `print(fromLabels[index].text` and see if they print `A B C D E`

Comment: It's printing in correct order like A B C D E.

Comment: @Mac_Play - see if you can create a minimal example project that reproduces this that you can share (either zip file on a file transfer site or GitHub project).

Comment: @DonMag one more thing I want to mention here is, previously the ui was in XIB file at that time no issue, the order was correct. Now I have changed it to storyboard and facing this issue.

Comment: @Mac_Play - if you share your project, I expect we could solve the issue in just a few minutes.